# how do I always include symbols from a static library?

Tags: c, windows, linux

Suppose I have a static library libx.a. How to I make some symbols (not all) from this library to be *always* present in any binary I link with my library? Reason is that I need these symbols to be available via dlopen+dlsym. I'm aware of --whole-archive linker switch, but it forces all object files from library archive to linked into resulting binary, and that is not what I want...

Observations so far (CentOS 5.4, 32bit) (**upd**: this paragraph is wrong; I could not reproduce this behaviour)

```
ld main.o libx.a
```

will happily strip all non-referenced symbols, while

```
ld main.o -L. -lx
```

will link whole library in. I guess this depends on version of binutils used, however, and newer linkers will be able to cherry-pick individual objects from a static library.

Another question is how can I achieve the same effect under Windows?

Thanks in advance. Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you have a project which consists of the following three C files in the same folder;

```
// ---- jam.h
 int jam_badger(int);

// ---- jam.c
 #include "jam.h"
 int jam_badger(int a)
 {
   return a + 1;
 }

 // ---- main.c
 #include "jam.h"
 int main()
 {
   return jam_badger(2);
 }
```

And you build it with a boost-build bjam file like this;

```
lib jam : jam.c <link>static ;

lib jam_badger : jam ;

exe demo : jam_badger main.c ;
```

You will get an error like this.

```
undefined reference to `jam_badger'
```

(I have used bjam here because the file is easier to read, but you could use anything you want)

Removing the 'static' produces a working binary,  as does adding static to the other library, or just using the one library (rather than the silly wrapping on inside the other)

The reason this happens is because ld is clever enough to only select the parts of the archive which are actually used, which in this case is none of them.

The solution is to surround the static archives with -Wl,--whole-archive  and -Wl,--no-whole-archive, like so;

```
g++ -o "libjam_candle_badger.so" -Wl,--whole-archive libjam_badger.a Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Not quite sure how to get boost-build to do this for you, but you get the idea.

Comment: Do you, by chance, have an idea how to do this via Apple Xcode build-settings? Xcode builds the command lines for itself. Using it's "Build Settings" form you can modify the way it works, and thus indirectly introduce linker flags, plus you can add your own "other linker flags", but I don't think they'll "wrap around" a specific input file/staticLib.

Answer (score 2):

First things first: `ld main.o libx.a` does not build a valid executable. In general, you should *never* use `ld` to link anything directly; *always* use proper compiler driver (`gcc` in this case) instead.

Also, `"ld main.o libx.a"` and `"ld main.o -L. -lx"` should be exactly equivalent. I am very doubtful you actually got different results from these two commands.

Now to answer your question: if you want `foo`, `bar` and `baz` to be exported from your `a.out`, do this:

```
gcc -Wl,-u,foo,-u,bar,-u,baz main.o -L. -lx -rdynamic
```

Update:
your statement: "symbols I want to include are used by library internally only" doesn't make much sense: if the symbols are internal to the library, why do you want to export them? And if something else uses them (via dlsym), then they are *not* internal to the library -- they are part of the library public API.

You should clarify your question and explain what you *really* are trying to achieve. Providing sample code will not hurt either.

Comment: 1. indeed, I cannot reproduce difference between -l and specifying library directly now. Maybe I did something wrong that time...

2. While -u looks like a solution, to use it I need to know list of "extra" symbols when building a binary. I would like to "hide" these dependencies (symbols I want to include are used by library internally only).

Answer (score 1):

I would start with splitting off those symbols you always need into a seperate library, retaining only the optional ones in `libx.a`.

Comment: seems to be the easiest and most practical way-to-goal, but I believe the OP wants a more elegant solution :)

Comment: @MottiShneor: Easy and practical *is* elegant. ;-) Gosh, this must be one of my *oldest* SO posts... :-D

Comment: I think there should be a linker flag for this, something like -whole-archive or similar. I came by this question and answer because I now suffer the opposite problem. My static lib's symbols just won't "go through" my Xcode Framework (which is a kind of dylib) and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Take an address of the symbol you need to include.

If gcc's optimiser anyway eliminates it, do something with this address - should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, but I already thought of this hack; I'm wondering if there are clean ways to do it.

Comment: @kolubsa: I wouldn't consider this a hack ... you need to reference the symbols in some way to make the linker pull them in.

Comment: @qrld Yes, but this way I will have to make symbols visible in some places where they are currently not (they are just sitting in separate object file...).

Comment: @kolbusa I didn't get it. If these symbols are not visible, `dlsym()` don't find them, so they have to be visible.

Comment: @qrld I mean that I need to put these address manipulations into a function that is a) publically visible and b) is always called. I do have such a function, but what I meant is that from code modularity point of view, putting such code there does not make much sense...