# linking a static library into an executable

Tags: c, makefile

My folder structure is as follows.

```
--->MyProgram
     | a.c
     | b.c
     | c.c 
     | libzint/
```

The libzint folder contains a makefile of its own and it creates libzint.a in the folder MyProgram.
When I call make in MyProgram folder. I want the libzint.a to be inserted into the executable printer.

If I do

```
$ nm printer | grep "libzint_function"
```

it doesn't show anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
PATHTOMAKEVARIABLES=../
include $(PATHTOMAKEVARIABLES)/Makefile.variable 

PREFIX := /usr

LIBDIR := $(PREFIX)/lib 
LIBDIR2 := .

PRJROOT:=.

INCDIRS := -I. -I./inc/ -I../lib/inc  -I./libzint
ECFLAGS := 

CFLAGS := -DPRN -D_GNU_SOURCE -O2 $(INCDIRS) $(ECFLAGS) 

LDFLAGS := -lrt -lm -lpthread -lclog -fpack-struct -L$(LIBDIR) -L$(LIBDIR2) 


OBJPATH := ./Debug
OUTPUTNAME := printer

SOURCES :=  $(PRJROOT)/src/a.c \
        $(PRJROOT)/src/b.c \
        $(PRJROOT)/src/c.c 

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

all: $(OUTPUTNAME)
    @echo "Build complete"

$(OUTPUTNAME) : clean $(OBJECTS) $(LIBZINT)
    @$(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(OUTPUTNAME) $(LDFLAGS) libzint.a

LIBZINT:
    $(MAKE) -C libzint

clean:
    @-$(RM) $(OBJECTS)
    @-$(RM) $(PRJROOT)/$(OUTPUTNAME)
```

If I try to include `libzint_funciton' in one of the`*.c`files in`MyProgram` I get the following errors.

```
libzint.a(png.o): In function `writepng_error_handler':
png.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `png_get_error_ptr'
libzint.a(png.o): In function `png_pixel_plot':
png.c:(.text+0x500): undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
png.c:(.text+0x54c): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
png.c:(.text+0x570): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
png.c:(.text+0x5cc): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
png.c:(.text+0x610): undefined reference to `png_init_io'
png.c:(.text+0x620): undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level'
png.c:(.text+0x670): undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR'
png.c:(.text+0x684): undefined reference to `png_write_info'
png.c:(.text+0x690): undefined reference to `png_set_packing'
png.c:(.text+0x7f4): undefined reference to `png_write_row'
png.c:(.text+0x94c): undefined reference to `png_write_row'
png.c:(.text+0xab0): undefined reference to `png_write_row'
png.c:(.text+0xc08): undefined reference to `png_write_row'
png.c:(.text+0xc38): undefined reference to `png_write_end'
png.c:(.text+0xc64): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: can you show the code where you're calling your lib function? also, what's the problem that blocks you? can you show a sample of `nm` output?

Comment: for instance, if you're not using `libzint_function`, most linkers don't include the code when passing a `.a`.

Comment: Does your build succeed after all?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I have tried including `linbzint_function` but then I am getting undefined reference.

Comment: that's because you need to link with `libpng` as well.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - that was helpful :) it worked.

Comment: I have updated my answer, which was not addressing your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(first part of the answer assumed that OP successfully linked his executable, which wasn't the case):

that happens if you're not using the symbol in any of your `.c` files.

When passing a `.a` file, the linker selects the internal object files which are referenced in the object files. Other symbols are discarded.

So unless you're calling `libzint_function` explicitly, the linker won't include the symbol.

You can force symbol inclusion without calling any functions from the lib with various techniques (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763038/how-do-i-always-include-symbols-from-a-static-library))

*The actual problem:*

**But** in your case, the executable is created but is invalid because of the unresolved symbols you're getting (saw that after you edited the question).

That's because the `libzint.a` file refers to symbols from `libpng`. You have to install that library (if not already installed) and link against it (*after* `libzint.a` of course):

```
@$(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(OUTPUTNAME) $(LDFLAGS) libzint.a -lpng
```